# Type error web crypto importKey algorithm parameter

Tags: typescript, webcrypto-api

I'm implementing the examples for pbkdf2 shown at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey).
My test code is

```
let enc = new TextEncoder();
let password = enc.encode("password");
window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
                "raw",
                password,
                {"name": "PBKDF2"},
                false,
                ["deriveBits", "deriveKey"]
                )
```

This results in the following error (typescript 3.3.4000):

```
credential.service.ts:6:3 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ "name": string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | AesKeyAlgorithm | EcKeyImportParams | HmacImportParams | RsaHashedImportParams | DhImportKeyParams'.
  Type '{ "name": string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'DhImportKeyParams': generator, prime

{"name": "PBKDF2"},
```

The code works fine in chrome.

Comment: Try to remove `"` from `"name"`

Comment: that leads to exactly the same error

Comment: Are you executing webcrypto on Edge? Seems PBKDF2 is not supported. See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9259365/

Comment: I haven't tried edge - chrome works.The problem is the typescript compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The following (ugly) workaround does the trick:

```
window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
                "raw",
                password,
                {
                    "name": "PBKDF2",
                    // the next two lines are just to trick typescript
                    "generator": new Uint8Array(12),
                    "prime": new Uint8Array(12)
                },
                false,
                ["deriveBits", "deriveKey"]
                )
```

It is ugly as it tricks typescript into thinking the `PBKDF2` object is something different than it acutally is.

Answer (score 0):

I think the example is wrong on that line. When you look above to the `Parameters section / algorithm` you will see that:

> For PBKDF2 : Pass the string PBKDF2.

So instead of `{name: 'PBKDF2'}` use just `'PBKDF2'`.

**MDN: SubtleCrypto.importKey()**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey#Parameters